# Unable to maximize command prompt from task bar

Tags: cmd.exe

Well, I am experiencing rather strange problem. While opening command prompt (cmd.exe) in windows 7, it opens, but is minimized to task bar, and I can't get it maximized....it is running, but struck at background. I can see it with windows+tab key.

Any clue what might be wrong ?

Comment: [Customize the Command Prompt in Windows 7](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff758104.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The best answer I can give is:

`wmic` + (<kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>UP</kbd>) + `exit` [+ `cls`]